# Returning a variable while using a post increment in C

Tags: c, global-variables, standards, c99, language-lawyer

I have a global variable called `var` and a function `foo`. (I know it's a bad practice but sometimes it's unavoidable) I'm wondering if the C standard (I'm compiling using c99) says what happens to `var` if I try to execute:

```
long foo(){
    return var++;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Its old value is returned, and the incremented value is stored.

Comment: Yes. It appears to be working as expected. I'm just not sure it's the right think to do judging by the standard.

Comment: It's fine - as fine as global variables are.

Comment: I added the "language-lawyer" tag to prevent this question from getting closed as "too localized".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer:

It will return a copy of `var` and then immediately afterwards increment the global `var`.

Long answer:

C11 6.5.2.4

> "The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As
>   a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented..". /--/
>   The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of
>   updating the stored value of the operand.

The standard 5.1.2.3 "Program execution" specifies that all *side effects* must have been evaluated before the program encounters a *sequence point*. (Plenty of into about sequence points can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)).

There is a sequence point after a `return` statement (C11 6.8/4).

This means that the expression `var++` is guaranteed to be completely evaluated before any code in main() continues.

Your machine code will look like this pseudo code:

- Store a local copy of `var` on the stack (or in a register etc)
- Increase the global `var` with 1.
- Return from sub routine.
- Use "copy-of-`var`".

Had you used prefix increment instead, the increase operation would have been sequenced before the copy was stored.

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that the above "machine code" illustrates why ++ on a global variable is not thread safe. A context switch between "store copy" and "increase" that acesses `var` (either to read or to write) may cause unexpected program behavior.

Answer (score 6):

As `var++` is a post-increment, it is basically something like this:

```
long foo(){
  long tmp = var;
  var++;
  return tmp;
}
```

If you use `++var` instead, it will return the incremented value (as it will increment the variable *before* returning its value).

Answer (score 2):

`foo()` will return the current value of `var`, and `var` gets increased.